# How to center attributed title in UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, nsattributedstring

I am trying to center multiline title of a UIButton

my Button:

```
let aButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        button.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        return button
    }()
```

to set the title I'm using a method that takes a string and font size and returns NSAttributedString (btw, I cannot modify that):

```
let title = markdownParser.parse(string: "my multiline string", fontSize: 15)
```

then I set up the button's title:

```
aButton.setAttributedTitle(title, for: .normal)
```

The text is still aligned to left, however, what is it that I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Constraints are set as below:

```
addSubview(aButton)
        aButton.snp.makeConstraints { maker in
            maker.center.equalToSuperview()
            maker.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview().inset(16)
        }
```

Comment: Normally button gets its intrinsic content size from its content (title and image) unless you are restricting the width of the button in someway title will never go to multiple lines, it will always be in a single line. Show us the code, how are you adding the button to view? What are the constraints?

Comment: Edited with contstraints set; currently I have text in 4 lines, but aligned to left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the text is an attributed String, you will need to align the text after it has been set.

Solution for you will be:

```
aButton.setAttributedTitle(title, for: .normal)
aButton.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
```

By setting attributed String, instead of String, you are clearing all the button's text property.

Nicer solution will be to add alignment attribute into the attributed String

Comment: eventually ended up modifying the method adding alignment to attributed String; aButton.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center placed after setting the text for attributed string didn't work

Comment: Yeah, thats because it is UILabel inside a UIButton. Some parent class functionality gets called each time the button title is set.